# Listening for keystrokes through a GSM module

Tags: gsm

So, I would like to connect a GSM module to my Pi to act as a phone, and be able to make a two-way call to my cellular phone. I know this is possible, and have seen a few tutorials on this (https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/piphone-home-made-raspberry-pi-smartphone/).

However, I am wondering if it is possible to have the Pi listen for keystrokes from my cellular phone during the two-way call. Ex) The Pi calls me on my cell phone, I pick up and a two way conversation is going, and when I press a number on my keypad, the Pi receives info of which number I pressed.

Is this possible and how would one go about doing it? Would I need to use something like asterisk?

Thank you

Comment: Yeah, it's completely possible. I've implemented it before in Asterisk, but can't really remember how.

Comment: Anyways, the right keyword is DTMF. Try doing some research about that. `DTMF decode raspberry pi` is a good Google search term.

Comment: Have you been successful in establishing phone on PI? I also have [such task now](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66443/voip-gsm-gateway-on-raspberry-pi2).

Comment: Nope, haven't worked on this in a while, but if anyone gets it to work I'd still be interested.